# unassigned vs non-assigned

Tags: grammaticality

We are developing modules in a ticket assignment system and most of the labels are in French. Someone has translated the label for unassigned tickets  to "Non-Assigned" in English. I'm not sure this is correct, can you please advise if I should have them change it to Unassigned? I think that sounds a lot better... "Unassigned" tickets vs "Non-Assigned" tickets.

Thanks for your help,
Patricia

Comment: Thank you all for your answers... it just confirms what I was thinking :)

Answer (score 3):

Ticketing systems use one word identifiers, and Non-Assigned does not fall into that category, I reckon.

- **Unassigned is the universally accepted term.**

About the first comment, a ticket is either unassigned because someone put it back, or nobody picked it up yet.

Non-assigned could imply that it's not going be assigned, ever. That's not how tickets work, or how they should work. Of course, most of my answer pertains to Software Development aiding ticketing systems.

Comment: In any context i can think of, "unassigned" is better than "non-assigned".

Answer (score -2):

I would see differences in the expressions:

unassigned = ticket assignment was cancelled

non-assigned = ticket was never assigned

this might be important distinction for many applications